# GUI wallet did not receive transfer despite confirmation from shapeshifter

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, language

So I tried to transfer funds from shapeshifter to monero gui wallet. The shapeshift website that the transaction was completed. But the funds never showed up. I asked the support of ShapeShifter to reverse the transaction (which they did immediately). My wallet is fully synced, so i'm wondering if I made a mistake without how I inputted my wallet information.

What I did was that i put down my monero gui wallet address and I generated a new payment ID. I notice now that I can specify the amount that i expect to receive. Do i need to fill that out when I generate a payment ID? Or is there something else that is going wrong with my GUI wallet

Comment: Did the transfer take place before the daemon sync was finished? See this: https://github.com/monero-project/monero-core/issues/363

Comment: no the sync was completely done before i did the transfer

Comment: You cannot "reverse" a Monero transaction. You do not need a payment id to receive funds. Payment ids are for people who are receiving large amounts of transactions and need a payment id to link funds received to a particular account. Monero is private so without a payment id they cannot know what deposits belong to who. That is why exchanges need a payment id. If you are receiving one or a couple of transfers, you know which is what so payment id is unnecessary.